# react-router 4 doesn't display components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

i'm having 2 routes in my react-redux app:

```
ReactDOM.render(

<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>

        <div>
            <Route path = '/a' component = {ContainerComponent} />
            <Route path = '/b' component = {ContainerComponent} />
        </div>      

    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, 

document.getElementById('app'));
```

- On http://localhost:8080/a i can see my ContainerComponent.
- On http://localhost:8080/b i can also see my ContainerComponent.
- But on http://localhost:8080/a/b i'm getting 404-error, although i expect to see two ContainerComponents at the same time, like i saw in many tutorials!

My webpack config:

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    entry:  __dirname + '/app/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }, {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader?modules,localIdentName="[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:6]"'
                })
            }]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'transformed.js',
        path: __dirname + '/build'
    },
    devServer: {

        historyApiFallback: true

    },
    plugins: [
        HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
        new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
    ]
};
```

[image: code]

[image: Result]

Comment: I am curious about those tutorials where it explains that composing url paths render multiple components at the same time. As far as I know the behaviour you are having is the expected and proper one.

Comment: That's not possible. Like @Dez said I'm also interested in those tutorials where they rendered multiple components by joining two routes.

Comment: @Dez  for example this one on youtube (7:00 - 7:20): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l9eyot_IXLY .I'm simply repeating his actions. <Route path = '/' works fine. <Route path = '/home' works fine. <Route path = '/home/2' doesnt work for me!

Comment: Oh, I see what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @John Kennedy My end goal here is to keep rendered component on the screen after modifying URL-string (adding JWT token). At the moment, my component is gone (error) after adding some characters to current URL. That's why i was interested to repeat what was done here: youtube.com/watch?v=l9eyot_IXLY on 7:00 - 7:20, but it doesn't work for me for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

```
ReactDOM.render(

<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>

        <div>
            <Route path = '/a' component = {ContainerComponent} />
            <Route path = '/b' component = {ContainerComponent} />
            <Route path = '/a/b' component = {ContainerComponent} />

        </div>      

    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>, 

document.getElementById('app'));
```

You need to define the third route also. Because of the functioning of the path matching, while not using the `exact` param, the `BrowserRouter` will match as many routes as defined whose path matches the URL browsed. In this case, with URL `/a`, you will get two components rendered. But if you browse URL `/a/b`, the only route that will match the path is the third one. Because you hadn't defined in your code you get a proper 404 error.

Comment: i've corrected the code, but still got 404 - error. http://localhost:8080/a - works fine. http://localhost:8080/b - works fine. http://localhost:8080/a/b -still gives me an error...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally, solved the problem by modifying ***webpack.config.js***. Replaced this:

```
output: {
    filename: 'transformed.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build',
},
```

with this:

```
output: {
    filename: 'transformed.js',
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    publicPath: '/'
},
```

Comment: I wonder [adding](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) a `basename='/'` to your Router will also work in your case.